# Insert value from table into another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, insert-into

I'm trying to insert the value of `ms_price` and `ms_name` to another table which is records for the `service_type` and `service_amount` column.

**ms_pricelist**

```
| ms_priceID | ms_Name | ms_price |
|------------|---------|----------|
| 7894       |Casing   | 17.0897  |
| 7895       |Fan      | 69.9902  |
```

**records**

```
| customerID | service_type | service_amount |
|------------|--------------|----------------|
| 1000712    | Casing       |  17.2311       |
| 1000712    | Trunion      | 189.9900       |
```

Here's my code.

```
INSERT INTO records (service_type, service_amount)
    SELECT ms_pricelist.ms_name, ms_pricelist.ms_price
    FROM records JOIN
         ms_pricelist
    WHERE records.CustomerNumber='1' AND ms_pricelist.ms_priceID='1'
```

It does what I want but it adds a new *record*(edit history: column). I want to UPDATE or INSERT it into an existing record in my records table.

**EDIT**

I just want to UPDATE an existing record that will insert the value of ms_name and ms_price (from ms_pricelist table) TO service_type and service_amount (records table).

So that in the end the **records** table would contain:

```
| customerID | service_type | service_amount |
|------------|--------------|----------------|
| 1000712    | Casing       |  17.0897       | <--Note: updated price
| 1000712    | Trunion      | 189.9900       |
| 1000712    | Fan          | 69.9902        | <--Note: new row
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  That is presumably MySQL, if this ill-formed syntax is accepted.  Also, sample data and desired results would help explain what you are doing.  `INSERT` does not add a *column*, so the question is unclear.

Comment: I'm using mysql. I can't make it work if I use UPDATE and it just returns bunch of errors. Maybe by using DUPLICATE or something? I edited the question.

Comment: Yes, sound like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is what you're looking for. 
Just make sure the table has a PRIMARY KEY defined

Answer (score 1):

You want a `MERGE` statement (if the database you have supports it):

```
CREATE TABLE ms_pricelist (
  ms_priceID int,
  ms_Name nvarchar(50),
  ms_price money
)

CREATE TABLE  records ( 
    customerID int,
    service_type nvarchar(50),
    service_amount money
  )

 MERGE records
 USING (
     SELECT 1000712 AS customerID, ms_name, ms_price
     FROM ms_pricelist
     wHERE ms_priceID = 7894
     ) AS rows(CustomerID, Name, Price)
 ON records.service_type = rows.Name
 AND records.customerID = 1000712
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
     SET service_amount = rows.Price
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT(customerID, service_type, service_amount)
     VALUES (rows.CustomerID, rows.Name, rows.Price);
```

If you the database engine you're using doesn't have `MERGE` then you have to do it the old fashioned way; with separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE`:

```
--Add any missing rows
INSERT INTO records (customerID, service_type, service_amount)
SELECT 1000712 AS CustomerID, ms_name, ms_price
FROM ms_pricelist
WHERE ms_priceID = 7894
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM records 
    WHERE records.service_type = ms_pricelist.ms_name
    AND records.customerID = 1000712)

--Update any existing rows
UPDATE records
SET service_amount = ms_pricelist.ms_price
FROM records
    INNER JOIN ms_pricelist
    ON records.service_type = ms_pricelist.ms_name
WHERE ms_pricelist.ms_priceID = 7894
AND records.customerID = 1000712
```

http://rextester.com/FEGQS79621

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM records
    INNER JOIN ms_pricelist
    ON records.service_type = ms_pric' at line 3. It returns this error on the Update. :(

Comment: I was writing it against SQL Server. You'll have to translate as appropriate into mysql's variant of SQL.